# Why did Captain Marvel even come back to Earth for "Endgame"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-marvel

So this is something that's been bugging me, and I've seen a few questions around Captain Marvel's role in the Infinity Gauntlet story, but not specifically this one.

At the end of *Avengers: Infinity War*

> Nick Fury calls Captain Marvel using the pager he gave her at the end of the *Captain Marvel* movie.

During the events of *Avengers: Endgame*, there is a scene where all the characters are talking via some holographic communication, and she tells them that the whole universe is like this and everywhere needs help, so she won't be around because she needs to help elsewhere.

If that is all true,

> then why even come back to Earth when in the first place when Fury paged her after the events of Infinity War? People were already vanishing when Fury used the pager and sent the message. She seemed to come back to Earth only because she was paged.

So people around Captain Marvel would have been vanishing at the same time. As far as Captain Marvel is concerned, Earth had the same problem as the rest of the universe (which actually is incidentally true). So what reason would she have to come back to Earth over going somewhere else? Why would coming back to Earth help solve a universe-wide problem?

Yes, she is from Earth, but until the 90s, she didn't even remember that. And with that in mind, since she does remember now, she hasn't really been back to Earth to have any recent connection to life on Earth.

Comment: Not a full answer, but Fury was her friend and he called her for help... likely she wanted to go see if he was ok.

Comment: Votes to close are also unnecessarily frowned upon: it's just a way to put a question into a state where it is made obvious what's needed for it to be developed into a full-bodied, appropriate question, and it puts a little pressure on users to put more effort into their phrasing.

Comment: Your question itself has the answer.. **Nick Fury calls Captain Marvel using the pager he gave her at the end of the Captain Marvel movie.**. when someone calls you, you give attention to that person, and if that person is important to you, also you gave that person a specific way to contact you, I'm sure that explains why she came to earth.. **To find out why Fury called her**

Comment: @Vishwa well, no, my question asks how that would ever make sense. If the whole universe is in trouble, and a friend you once knew 30 years ago pages you (with no message), then why would you go straight to that one person, and basically skip the rest of the universe?

Comment: @searchengine27 Like I said, that one friend is very important to you and one of the few close people you have on certain planet. plus she told him, when she gave the pager to fury and said *if you need me...*. She knows that fury would call for help **only if** he needs it badly. So she knows when fury calls her, something terrible has happened. Coming for fury doesn't mean that she abandoned nor skip helping the universe(others).. that shows simply, that you do something if you care about someone.. basically it really makes sense

Answer (score 10):

It would take time for Captain Marvel confirm that the effects of the Snap were truly universal. At first all she would know is that people were disappearing around her (assuming there was anyone around to disappear, if she was in space alone at the time she may not have noticed anything was wrong). With no immediate explanation as to what is going on around her and no idea what to do to fight it the only clue she would have is the emergency signal from Earth that went off right at the same time.

When Carol shows up on Earth in the Captain Marvel end credits scene she very urgently asks "Where's Fury?", as if she hopes he might have some idea what just happened.

Comment: Either that, or she just wanted to make sure he hadn't disappeared too (which, of course, he had). Either way, she definitely came back to look for him.

Comment: Yea this has always bugged me too. I suppose we don't know what happened (socially speaking) between Captain Marvel and Fury between the events of Captain Marvel (movie) and the events of End Game (maybe she came back at some point and they were close friends) so anything is possible, but to think that Fury is the top of her list where she must travel the whole universe just to see if he and only he is OK, never sat well with me. And to think that Nick Fury has answers to a universal 'villian' wielding pre-universe Infinity Stones doesn't sit well with me either

Comment: I think by "Where's Fury" she just means literally that, since she gave the beeper to him, and he wasn't there. As far as we know, she is unaware of anything to do with Thanos and the effects of the Snap at the time of that scene.

Comment: I think you're wrong about that. The MCU has gone to great lengths to basically say as much - that she definitely knows about Thanos, the infinity stones, and what Thanos is likely to do with them (based on his past visits to other planets).

Comment: @searchengine27 If Captain Marvel knew the true after effects of Thanos' plan, she would have come to Earth/Titan sooner to try and stop him. I don't think she knew about Thanos' 50% plan.

Answer (score 6):

When Captain Marvel gives Nick Fury the pager she tells him, in no uncertain words

> For emergencies only

This isn't a friendly chat.  This isn't a "just checking in".  If this pager is going off, it is *literally* a case of Life-or-Death, Get-your-butt-back-here-NOW-(please).  Ignoring it would defeat the whole reason that she created it and gave it to Nick Fury.

Considering that it also seems to be known (in at least *some* circles) that Earth has successfully fought off the Chitauri and the Dark Elves, all without calling Captain Marvel in — and that Ronan the Accuser (plus Power-Hammer) was defeated by an Earthling-led team — would also lend credence to this being an important matter, requiring her (almost) immediate attention.